# Generate random activation code in PHP

Tags: php, random, activation-codes

How to generate random activation code based on current datetime and username in PHP.

The return value should be like this, i.e:

201605021955Username

```
function getActivationCode($username){
$activationCode = "";        

 ....

return activationCode;
}
```

Comment: You could write your own function using [`uniqid`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) or if you need security with a cryptographic function.

Comment: In your example, you seem to be using the datetime (as you've requested), but not in any sort of random way. 201605021955 - I'm assuming that's 05, 02, 2016 19:55:00 (or as you've put it 2016, 05, 02 19:55)? How exactly is that *random*? Are your requirements not for a random number but rather for a **precise timestamp**?

Comment: @NateI I think he wants a unique code rather than a random one, perhaps

Comment: yes, my bad, it should have random 3-digit number after the username

Comment: @Fale1994 `sprintf("%03d",rand(0,1000));` will give you three random digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not random, but:

```
$string = date('YmdHi') . $username;
```

Also check out [chr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php) function to get a character from a random number (which you can get from [mt_rand](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php)).

Comment: what if there are 2x "John"'s? That will produce the same string within the same "possible" (minute) timeframe, should there be the same username.

Comment: Yeah, he should use either `rand` or `mt_rand` to add random numbers to the string to avoid collision, that's why I recommend to check out the possibility.

Comment: What's point of using such a highly predictable activation code. This is too vulnerable.

Comment: It's literally what the user asked for, I already mentioned in the answer and comment one year ago that it's better to add a randomised string.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getActivationCode($username){
    $activationCode =date('YmdHi').$username;  
    return activationCode;
}
```